# Select all a tags that are in certain class

Tags: html, css

How do I select with css all a tags that are in a div that has `class = class1`

Let's say I have this structure(just an example):

```
 <div class="class1"> 
         <div> <a>should be selected</a> </div>
         <p><span> <a>should be selected</a> </span></p>  
         <a>should be selected</a>
 </div>
 <a>should not be selected</a>
```

How do I select all `a` elements that are in `div` with class1 and not somewhere else.
I tried to do 
`.class1 > a { }` but it doesn't select all a tags I need

Comment: Try using .class1 > a{} for getting direct child element and for getting all child element use .class a {}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your selector

> .class > a

```css
.class1 > a {
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div> <a>should be selected</a> 
  </div>
  <p><span> <a>should be selected</a> </span>
  </p>
  <a>Just this will be selected</a>
</div>
```

Just target the direct descendents that are `a` tags inside `.class` . Just travel one level deep.

With

> .class a

```css
.class1 a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div> <a>should be selected</a> 
  </div>
  <p><span> <a>should be selected</a> </span>
  </p>
  <a>should be selected</a>
</div>
```

You select all `a` tags inside `.class`. All levels.

Answer (score -1):

Does this only work for a tags? Would it work for selecting a div

Comment: should be a comment, this is not an answer